# The Flash (Vol. 2) where Wally West casually fetches the Cosmic Treadmill from the past under his own power?

Tags: dc, comics, episode-identification, the-flash

There's a 2-3 panel sequence during the Wally West era of *The Flash* (volume 2), when the Flash Family are planning to save the world or something.  At the time, Wally is the only Flash who can time travel under his own power and the plan requires other speedsters use the Cosmic Treadmill to time travel as well.  The catch is that the Cosmic Treadmill was destroyed in a fire or attack.

Wally solves the problem in 1-2 panels by popping into the past to pick up the Cosmic Treadmill *before* its destruction and bringing it back to the present (its future) to be used in their plan.  The feat is accomplished completely without fanfare and done matter-of-factly as if there are absolutely no greater implications to being able to do this casually.

I can't remember the issue or context beyond that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is issue #145, published in 1999. Here are the panels matching your recollection:

> JAY: Time travel? Wally, I know *you* can zip through time on your own, but haven't you forgotten? The rest of us need the Cosmic Treadmill -- and t must have been destroyed when Cobalt Blue demolished the Flash Museum!
>
> WALLY: Luckily, no. Know why? Because I've just blitzed through time myself -- and lifted it just before the museum was totaled. Any other questions?

[image: Wally fetches the Treadmill]

---

Found by Googling `flash "wally west" "cosmic treadmill" "the flash vol 2" site:dc.fandom.com/wiki -"wally west flashback only"`; the preview of [the issue's Wikia page](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/The_Flash_Vol_2_145) looked promising as it said

> Using the Cosmic Treadmill, each of the speedsters sets off on their mission.

Comment: That's it! Thanks.